# TYPO3 custom form setup with EXT: Powermail KEY: powermail VER: 2.0.10

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I have setup the Powermail and its working fine on TYPO3 v. 6.1 FLUID/EXTBASE.

My question is now.. Is there a way to setup this extension so i can 100% make my own layout with

2 text fields span6

1 text field span 12

1 textarea 5cols 8rows

1 captcha

1 submit button.

As u can see i want to use some span/class style with 6 and 12 span, but i can't make this in the normal setup, so if its possible to make some in typoscript i want to do that.

I can see i can make it with tt_news.. but here its only the page layout i want to changes.

Can I do that...have tried to google it, but can't find anything about "TYPO3 Powermail custom layout".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powermail simply adds each field after the last field.
To add some own CSS-classes, you can use the style selection for editors

See manual:
http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/powermail/2.0.10/view/1/50/#idp21854080 and search for "TCEFORM"

Comment: Yes I can se that, but my problem is, that if I add 3 text fields then it's using the same layout - I can't make diffrent layout with span classes for the text fields.. But i will try to look at u'r link.